# How do I convert an object to an array in php

Tags: php

Hi I have been trying to figure out how to convert an object to an array I have tried using json_decode but that doesn't turn it into a nested array but it looks like the picture below becuase I am using angular I need everything to be in an array can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

What the data currently looks like when I use json_decode
[image]

The PHP function:

```php
public function getForm(Request $request)
{
    try
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $form = admin_form::find($id);
        if($form) {
        $form = admin_form::where('id',$id)->with('fields')->first();
        $res['Message'] = "Success";
        $res['Status'] = true;
        $res['results'] = json_decode($form, true);
        return response($res, 200);
        } else {
            $res['status'] = false;
            $res['message'] = "Form not found";
            return response($res, 404);
        }
    } catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
        $res['status'] = false;
        $res['message'] = $ex->getMessage();
        return response($res, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript does not know the concept of associative arrays, so what you have shown in your screenshot _can not_ be converted into an array, and keep the keys at the same time.

Comment: The heading says PHP not javascript, I have also posted my answer on how I fixed this

Comment: You said you needed this as an array because you are using angular …

Comment: Yes because an ngFor  can only loop through arrays unless I use keyvalue pipe but I didn't want to so I changed the code in my API to send it as an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone having the problem I had this is how I sloved it

```js
public function getForm(Request $request)
{
    try
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $form = admin_form::find($id);
        if($form) {
        $form = admin_form::where('id',$id)->with('fields')->first();
        $res['Message'] = "Success";
        $res['Status'] = true;
        $res['results'] = [$form->getAttributes()];
        return response($res, 200);
        } else {
            $res['status'] = false;
            $res['message'] = "Form not found";
            return response($res, 404);
        }
    } catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
        $res['status'] = false;
        $res['message'] = $ex->getMessage();
        return response($res, 500);
    }
}
```

The reason this worked for me was because the $form is an object with all of the information about what I am trying to get and when you do a dd($form) all of the information that it gets from the DB is stored in the attributes array and lumen has a getAttributes() function and from there I put them into [] to get an array

But if you have a relationship with another table then don't use getAttributes just use the [] braces

Answer (score 0):

As I know you don't need to convert object to array, cause you can iterate over it in ng-repeat. Try to use the following syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in results">{{key}} => {{val}}</div>
```

According to [ng-repeat documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: Nope it didn't work results still instant an array but thank you for you're assistance

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it was just a part of his code. It should be 200, yeap, thanks.

Comment: I put it in where my 200 response is and still not in an array data is same as picture but it just has {} braces now also the 200 is the first return the last one is the 500

Comment: The problem with key-value pair is I don't think you can specifically use certain values, Im pretty sure you have to display all of the values because all I want to display from the data is the form name and organization.

Answer (score 0):

create a variable and store json init and pass response as parameter

```
var test = json.parse(response);
```

Comment: is $res['results'] not a var? also when I use this code I get a 500 error